# How to add "long" documents to CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

How to create long and complex documents and add them to CouchDB? Is there any editor that I can use and then PUT the file using CRUD?

Thank you

Hugo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in Futon.

1. Either click on an existing document, or click the "New Document" link. You will be in the standard key/value editor.
2. Click the "Source" tab in the upper-right.
3. Double-click the document body. It will change to a large <textarea> input field where you can edit the document freely.
4. When you are done, click the green check mark. It will confirm that your edits are valid JSON.
5. Click Save Document. That will either create or update the document (depending on what you clicked in step 1)